# While generating video thumbnail, Image automatic rotate into landscape

Tags: c#, video, video-thumbnails, video-conversion, nreco

While generating video thumbnail from c#, when video in portrait mode then that video thumbnail image automatic convert into landscape mode.

I am using **NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter** library
Below is my code snippet

```
var ffMpeg = new NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter();
ffMpeg.GetVideoThumbnail(filePath, SnippetsVideoThumbUploadPath + guid + ".jpeg", 1);
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: @nilsK My question is like when i am generating video thumbnail, if i take video on portrait mode then that time that particular video thumbnail image generate in landscape image. i need to generate image in portrait if i take video in portrait mode

Comment: @DanWilson Please see my above comment, if you can't get it then please let me know again,

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg (which is internally used when GetVideoThumbnail is called) automatically rotates video frame according to the video metadata. If you want to get the frame 'as is' you need to specify `-noautorotate` option:

```
ffMpeg.ConvertMedia(filePath, null, SnippetsVideoThumbUploadPath + guid + ".jpeg", "mjpeg",
  new ConvertSettings() {
    VideoFrameCount = 1,
    Seek = 1,  // this is 3rd param of GetVideoThumbnail
    MaxDuration = 1,
    CustomInputArgs = "-noautorotate"
  });
```

(this call is equivalent to "GetVideoThumbnail" functionality but allows you to specify any additional ffmpeg options)

Comment: While i am using your solution i am facing error please check error and stack trace Error : Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
Stack Trace : at NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter.ConvertMedia(Media input, Media output, ConvertSettings settings)
   at MobileService.Service.UploadSnippets_V2(String CustomerId, String SnippetsType)